# Server not found in Kerberos database due to multiple DNS entries for single IP

Tags: api, sharepoint, kerberos, reverse-dns, mit-kerberos

There is a SharePoint which I'm accessing a file using REST API through Kerberos authentication , the problem is that the SharePoint where it is located has two DNS entries for a single IP, whenever it resolves to domain name 1, the API is getting authenticated and I'm getting back response , but whenever the DNS is resolving to domain name 2 , the authentication fails with error : ' server not found in Kerberos database '
And this DNS resolution is random

What needs to be done to solve this problem ?
Or how can I add this second DNS entry to Kerberos database ??

"The network administrators are not ready to remove 2nd DNS entry ! "

Comment: Steve has provided the solution and it will work. However, "this DNS resolution is random" -> did you mean that the DNS value can change dynamically? if that's the case, you need to update the SPN entry every time the DNS value changes.

Comment: DNS Resolution random here means that it's switching between name 1 and name 2 for random interval of time like for 4 hrs it resolves to name 1 and then next 3hrs it resolves to name 2 like that,

Comment: Then Steve's answer will solve your issue. Attach both DNS values as SPNs for the service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an SPN (servicePrincipalName) for the second domain name to the AD service account or computer object that runs SharePoint in the form of `http/your.second.domain.com`.